# Get percentage between numbers and add results to div

Tags: jquery

Im trying to calculate the percentage between numbers and ad the results to a div.

The HTML looks something like below - two divs with numbers and a placeholder a element for the results.  One of the divs has a number i cant control with currency symbol, a dot and a space in the end - the second number i set manually and can control.

First I tried the script from this thread: [jquery: percentage of two numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13620439/solved-jquery-percentage-of-two-numbers)

But I couldn't get that to work.

Second I tried this script:

```
$('.left').each (function() {
        var frstCol = $(this).find('em.price.product-card-price').text();
        var seCol = $(this).find('em.price.product-card-price.before').text(); 
       alert(frstCol)

           var result = (parseInt(frstCol) / parseInt(seCol))* 100 ;
           console.log(result);
           if(isNaN(result))
             $(this).find('a.pricebubble').text(0);
           else
             $(this).find('a.pricebubble').text(result);

    });
```

This outputs a number, 100, which of course is not correct.

How do I do this? It needs to be in an .each functions since I have several elements, and I need the numbers to be rounded of to an even number, like -16%, -50% etc.

```
<div class="left">
 <em class="price product-card-price">€1.019&nbsp;<span class="vatstatus">Exclusief BTW</span></em>
 <em class="price product-card-price before">1519</em>
 <a class="pricebubble"></a>
```

Comment: your price contains pound sign. That one is making the problem.

Comment: what are the values you getting in var frstCol and seCol ?

Comment: Please provide jsfiddle for this question

Comment: @AnoopJoshi yes I understand this, but I cant remove it. It is inserted dynamically and needs to be showed.

Comment: You should use form inputs and the method `.val()` as it is in the previous question. If there's a form field that has a constant value, you give it readonly attribute.

Comment: @GSB i tried to recreate this in a fiddle, but that script I show wont output the faulty numbers in the fiddle, it does however create an number in the live environment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue with your code is that the `text()` values from the `em` elements cannot be directly converted to numbers using `parseInt`. You need to remove the Euro symbol, the thousand separator and ensure the start of the string is the first digit of the numerical value by using `trim()`. From there your calculation works:

```
$('.left').each(function() {
    var frstCol = parseInt($(this).find('em.price.product-card-price').text().trim().replace(/[€\.]/g, ''), 10);
    var seCol = parseInt($(this).find('em.price.product-card-price.before').text().trim(), 10);        
    var result = (frstCol / seCol) * 100;
    $(this).find('a.pricebubble').text(result || 0);
});
```

[**Working example**](https://jsfiddle.net/28dL2fvp/1)

Comment: Works good, one thing that confused me though - I tried a number that should give me a 33% difference, it showed 67.08360763660302%? Is it possible to reverse the numbers, and trim it to remove the everything after the decimal(dot)?

Comment: You can amend the calculation on the integer values to be whatever you require. To round the figures, use `toFixed()`, eg. `parseInt(result)` but note this will change the value to a string.

Comment: Thanks for the help Rory, `result.toFixed(0)` fixed the trim issue. Unsure how to display 33% instead of 67% though.

Comment: It may be worth starting a new question for that.

Comment: Yeah maybe, not sure how to formulate the question though. and I cant start a new question until 90 minutes :)

Answer (score 0):

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/0y2utp82/3/)

You put your pound value in a separate span with and id `<span id="pounds">1.019</span>` and perform the operations as you did

```
    <div class="left">
<em class="price product-card-price">€<span id="pounds">1.019</span>&nbsp;<span class="vatstatus">Exclusief BTW</span></em>
 <em class="price product-card-price before">1519</em><br/>
 <a class="pricebubble"></a>
 </div>

$('.left').each (function() {
        var frstCol = $(this).find('em.price.product-card-price #pounds').text().split('.').join("");
    var seCol = $(this).find('em.price.product-card-price.before').text().split('.').join("");
       //alert(frstCol+'  '+seCol)

           var result = (parseInt(frstCol) / parseInt(seCol))* 100 ;
           console.log(result);
           if(isNaN(result))
             $(this).find('a.pricebubble').text(0);
           else
             $(this).find('a.pricebubble').text(result);
             alert(result)
    });
```

Comment: Don't forget to remove the thousand separator too.