# Calculate percentage between numbers, show the minus number

Tags: jquery

Im trying to calculate the percentage between numbers and add the results to a div. I have gotten some great help from the user Rory in this thread: [Get percentage between numbers and add results to div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37695631/get-percentage-between-numbers-and-add-results-to-div/37695801#37695801)

However, I think I asked the question wrong, the script below shows the percentage as 66%, where I want to show it as 33%.

https://jsfiddle.net/28dL2fvp/3/

How do I reverse the numbers?

```
$('.left').each(function() {
var frstCol = parseInt($(this).find('em.price.product-card-price').text().trim().replace(/[€\.]/g, ''), 10);
var seCol = parseInt($(this).find('em.price.product-card-price.before').text().trim(), 10);        
var result = (frstCol / seCol) * 100;
$(this).find('a.pricebubble').text(result || 0);
});
```

Comment: `1000/1500=0.66` And `1000` is `66.66%` of `1500`. I guess I am clear. What's the problem?

Comment: "*How do I reverse the numbers?*" - first, please explain why you *want* to reverse the numbers; what problem are you trying to solve? What information are you trying to convey with the calculation(s); what is the percentage the percentage *of*?

Comment: @DavidThomas *What is the percentage the percentage of?* - *You are confusing my confusion!*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's see the calculation.

- Number #1: `1000`
- Total: `1500`

Let's say, `1000` is two parts and `1500` is three parts. This means, `1000` is two-thirds of `1500`, which is `66.66%`. And that's right.

In simple terms, if you wanna reverse it, i.e. find the rest of the value, just negate it from the percentage:

```
$('.left').each(function() {
  var frstCol = parseInt($(this).find('em.price.product-card-price').text().trim().replace(/[€\.]/g, ''), 10);
  var seCol = parseInt($(this).find('em.price.product-card-price.before').text().trim(), 10);        
  var result = 100 - (frstCol / seCol) * 100;
  $(this).find('a.pricebubble').text(result || 0);
});
```

**Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/yf6ddabg/**